# Why can't I init Alamofire 4 session manager?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm having issues initalizing an Alamofire 4.0 session manager. My code as below:

```
func configAlamoManager() {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
        if Features.JWT_AUTH {
            let user = SessionManager.getCurrentUser()
            if let jwtToken = user.jwtToken {
                let bearer = "Bearer \(jwtToken)"
                configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["MyCompany-Authorization": bearer, "MyCompany-User-Agent": Config.MyCompanyUserAgentDataString]
            } else {
                configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["MyCompany-User-Agent": Config.MyCompanyUserAgentDataString]
            }
        }

        alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

    }
```

For the line `alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)` I am getting the error "Cannot invoke SessionManager with an argument list of type (configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)". What is the issue here? I am following the docs: `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#modifying-the-session-configuration`. I seem to be initializing the session manager in exactly the same way. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have this line :

```
var alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager
```

but with this line you invoke the common `Alamofire.SessionManager` initialization.

Try to declare your global property as:

```
var alamoManager = SessionManager()
```

so it become a generic `SessionManager` type with the default `SessionManager` initialization.